# Google Cloud Endpoints giving error when POST data having multilines

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When I am POSTing simple JSON like

> {\"body\": \"test\",\"subject\": \"test\"}

it's working fine but when I am posting data like (below)

> {"body": "hello
>
> First Name Paul A Alabisi Last Name  Customer ID 31877 Serail Key
>   2512948ead29a82d","subject": "hi"}

Here is the Error

> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "parseError",
>       "message": "Parse Error"    }   ],   "code": 400,   "message": "Parse Error"  } }

Here is my Objective C code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
```

`[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

```
//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server
NSString *dataPost = @"{\"body\": \"email body\",\"subject\": \"email subject\"}";

//Check The Value what we passed
NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", dataPost);

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [dataPost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
if(resSrt)
{
    NSLog(@"got response");
    /* ViewController *view =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:NULL];
     [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];*/
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"faield to connect");
}
```

Comment: Can you see the POST message body received by the server? It looks like the blank line is truncating the HTTP message body after the *hello*, causing invalid JSON to be received (I assume you missed out the closing `}` in your first example).

Comment: The server is not getting the request (I have seen in logs) so there is no way that I can give you the message (as it is not handled by endpoints). I apologise for '}' I mistakenly left it. (i have updated it in question. Also, as its a body of email it will have have 'enters' and other html code. many thanks for replying @tx802

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid JSON. You must escape newlines because they are control characters, e.g. use `\n` instead of an actual newline.

See the [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) section 2.5.